# Depth-First Search : Wrong Iterative DFS results order

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, math

I'm trying to sort my isometric rectangle with DFS algorithm. The **Recursive** version works perfectly.
Here's my implementation :

```
            if (node.discovered)
                return;

            node.discovered = true;

            for (var i:int = 0, length:int = node.behindNodes.length; i < length; i++)
            {
                var currentNode:IsoNode = node.behindNodes[i];

                if (!currentNode.discovered)
                {
                    visitNode(currentNode, container);
                }
            }

            container.addChild(node);
```

However the **Iterative** algorithm, which posted everywhere (for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) gives me absolutely wrong order.

Here's my implementation :

```
    if (node.discovered)
        return;

    var stack:Vector.<IsoNode> = new <IsoNode>[node];

    while (stack.length)
    {
        var currentNode:IsoNode = stack.pop();

        if (currentNode.discovered)
            continue;

        currentNode.discovered = true;

        for (var i:int = 0, length:int = currentNode.behindNodes.length; i < length; i++)
        {
            var behindNode:IsoNode = currentNode.behindNodes[i];

            if (!behindNode.discovered)
            {
                stack.push(behindNode);
            }
        }

        container.addChild(currentNode);
    }
```

> Seems like it's trying to place the parent node first instead of child at
> the end of chain

Why this version of algorithm even exists? Feels like this is half-reversed version of original algorithm.

How do I fix it? How do I make it return same result as recursive version? Because at first glance looks like I need to provide to this version completely formed stack (instead of using algorithm itself), but it make no sense!

Sorting idea is to get isometric nodes in correct order - from farthest to nearest. Each node holds information about nodes behind.

so basically we have graph

```
node_1->()  
node_2->(node_3)  
node_3->(node_1)
```

Example of **recursive** version:
**correct** order: node_1 node_3 node_2

[image: recursive]
<sub>(source: [yiffa.net](http://yiffa.net/i/4tX.png))</sub>

Example of **iterative** version:
**incorrect** order: node_1 node_2 node_3

[image: iterative]
<sub>(source: [yiffa.net](http://yiffa.net/i/4tY.png))</sub>

Comment: **but iterative algorithm... gives me absolutely wrong order**. You could try `var behindNode:IsoNode = currentNode.behindNodes[ length - i ];` to get a reverse. Now Is it the order you want?

Comment: Still wrong order. No matter in which order children go. It seems I need to change parent-child comprihation, but even if I change my edge-finding algorithm to get fore nodes, iterative DFS gives me wrong order anyway.

Comment: If this line `stack.push(behindNode);` is adding reverse order then just let it   run till finished with all nodes then do a `stack.reverse();` afterwards you then do another for loop that reads the newly reversed order into`container. Otherwise update your question with a **fully testable example code**...

Comment: updated with fully testable example code

Comment: **note:** I've updated your tags. I also tagged **MATLAB** since some users might have dealt with this issue. They'll understand the C-like code hopefully.

Comment: @VC.One Why would the MATLAB tag be applicable here? I understand C-like code just fine, but I'm not going to wade through this sea of code (I mean really, keyboard callbacks?) with not even an example of the expected and received outputs.

Comment: There's no need to dive into all this code. Only in two first fragments. They are two most common realizations of DFS found over internet. But I can't handle why with the same input their output are different. Seems to me like some kind of cruel joke

Comment: @Beaker from MathWork's MATLAB help docs... "Using MATLAB, you can analyze data, **develop algorithms**, and create models and applications." Its an academic standard in (computer) math. It's not about code language, its about the brains of MATLAB users (likely dealt with this). I agree about the sea of code, **I recommended it** thinking he would show a small/simple generic test with arrays. I'll edit later but its that first **Sorter** class that you'd need to look at really in his full example code...

Comment: @user1496491 You still haven't shown us an example input with your expected and received output.

Comment: @VC.One I understand MATLAB just fine. I don't know why that makes a difference in answering a question on AS-3 or graph algorithms.

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag as MATLAB != C, so don't add it. Might as well tag it java,python,C++ and ruby just to get more views from people who might or might not be familiar with the concept.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan We all follow tags and my logic was there's likely more mathophiles following MATLAB tag more than Ruby tag etc. Yes `MATLAB != C` but we need their brains & math backgrounds here. That's why!! What you did is for the best though, looks like people cant think beyond expecting MATLAB code if that tag exists...

Comment: @VC.One and rightly people expect the problem to be MATLAB related when it's got that tag. That's what it's for after all. "Mathophiles" will follow the tag "math" so there's no problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave my answer unaccepted, because maybe I'm wrong about that common iterative DFS.

I guess, I figured it out all by myself how to correctly simulate the stack for this algorithm.

Here's my code:

```
if (node.discovered)
    return;

var currentNode:IsoNode = node;

currentNode.discovered = true;

var discoveredStack:Vector.<IsoNode> = new <IsoNode>[currentNode];

while (discoveredStack.length)
{
    currentNode = discoveredStack[discoveredStack.length - 1];

    while (currentNode.behindNodes.length)
    {
        var behindNode:IsoNode = currentNode.behindNodes.pop();

        if (!behindNode.discovered)
        {
            behindNode.discovered = true;
            discoveredStack.push(behindNode);
            currentNode = behindNode;
        }
    }

    container.addChild(discoveredStack.pop());
}
```

Anyway, as for me, it doesn't matter if algorithm iterative or recursive. If algorithm is same and it has same input it must return the *same result*. Otherwise it's a different algorithm.

It would be so nice if somebody could tell whether am I right or wrong.

Comment: "If algorithm is same and it has same input it must return the *same result*." You say this with such confidence. Perhaps you could give us a sample input and the corresponding correct and incorrect outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems to me that you ran into the problem I read about in a blog post titled [Stack-based graph traversal ≠ depth first search](https://11011110.github.io/blog/2013/12/17/stack-based-graph-traversal.html).

I strongly suggest reading the blog post, but the short summary is that an iterative DFS implementation has gained widespread popularity despite being incorrect. The blog post specifically calls out the the algorithm described on Wikipedia as being affected, but this seems to have been remedied since then. The fix is checking the visited status of vertices after popping them from the stack instead of before pushing them there. For details, see the blog post linked above.